# Making my html link to my css files correctly

Tags: html, css, http, https

I've been using w3schools for a long time and i've never had a problem linking css to my html until today. I have a whole bunch of files referenced as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://enviroptics.com/Matt/css/styles.css"/>
```

And I checked the url and when i go to the page everything looks correct in the css, but for some reason it isnt pulling the styles into the html the way it has been for the last 6 months for me... I tried using the chrome editor to see what the problem and it says that my file is not https. It never has been https and i have been using it for many months with no problem.

Does anyone know why it would stop working all of a sudden? Is there another editor that i might be able to use? jsfiddle also tells me i need https..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you just switched to https? OR the site you're using - has that switched?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? Sometimes old css files get cached and don't represent the changes in the new file.

Comment: @CalvT no and i cant really switch either. I'm confused why it has never been a problem before

Comment: @ChadFisher yes i cleared the cache. Sadly it did not help. The error message is as follows: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://enviroptics.com/Matt/css/styles.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @MatthewSirkin I guess W3Schools must of just switched to HTTPS, so now all attached has to be HTTPS - which your CSS is not, so is blocked

Comment: Are you trying to load your site via `https`? That is `https://example.com` vs `http://example.com`. If so, all your resources should be requested via `https` also, your snippet above is not. It's requesting it over `http`.

Comment: @MatthewSirkin try http://codepen.io/ - they still use http, so your CSS will load correctly

Comment: @hungerstar i cant use https, my site isnt a secure site, it only has http. I think you need to pay for your site to be secure, dont you?

Comment: @MatthewSirkin your site will still work,  just not while you are trying to test it on W3Schools

Comment: So you're not requesting the stylesheet from your site? But from some other site? If so, and the site that isn't yours is using `https` then you will need to serve your CSS over `https` also.

Comment: @MatthewSirkin yes, you do need to pay for an SSL certificate and install it to make your site `https`. The point both CalvT and I are making is that if a the site itself uses `https` then all resources being loaded into the page also have to be requested over `https`. CalvT pointed out CodePen can be **loaded non-securely** over `http` and your CSS will work because it's also being requested non-securely with `http`. CodePen can also be **loaded securely** via `https//codepen.io`. If you use your `http` URL to your CSS, you'll get the same error message and your file won't be loaded.

Comment: @hungerstar no SSL certificates are free from organisations such as Lets Encrypt

Comment: @CalvT i tried codepen and got the same error. Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/matts1234/pen/ggyGym' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://enviroptics.com/Matt/css/responsiveslides.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @CalvT ...sort of. They do issue SSL certificates but not all certificates are the same. Lets Encrypt provides _"low level"_ certificates, [read more here](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/02/things-about-letsencrypt/).

Comment: @hungerstar okay that makes sense to me. so since since w3schools is https i can only load resources that are https. But I cant make my css files be https so i just cant use w3schools? Also i know it will work in the live website (and it does) but I have no way of editing it and viewing it before i publish any changes. Id like an easy way to edit the website, the way i used to with w3schools

Comment: @MatthewSirkin you are understanding correctly. Is there a reason you're not using your own browser to test your site (CSS)?

Comment: @hungerstar what do you mean by that? Sorry for my lack of knowledge on the topic. Basically im using a hosting platform called mawebcenters which is like WYSIWYG type website builder. Drop down menus and such. However they have a field where you can insert code, but theres no real way to view what the code will look like until you publish it and go to the live website. So i just went to w3schools and test the code there and then copy and paste it

Comment: @MatthewSirkin what markup (HTML) are you using to test with via W3Schools when linking to your CSS to check changes? Are you simply inserting markup plus linking to your CSS?

Comment: what is meant by what markup? My entire code has a lot of html in the body, some css files being referenced some javascript being referenced, and then some styles directly in the header and also some javascript directly in the body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135877/discussion-between-hungerstar-and-matthew-sirkin).

Answer (score 0):

1. open http://enviroptics.com/Matt/css/styles.css.
2. copy all.
3. open blocknotes or simple text editor
4. paste all
5. save file( name = styles.css )
6. insert this file in Matt/css in your web server ( ftp )
7. add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Matt/css/styles.css"/>` in your code html -> head

Comment: Problem is I have like 20 css files that im referencing and thats just for this page. It'd be quite annoying to go in and grab the text from each different file. Plus if i need to work on a different page that references different files id have to just do it again

Comment: Have you read through the comments? OP is loading the CSS in question through another site that uses `https` and not from their own domain like one would initially think.

Comment: you can not import from https to http files. the only remedy is this. We must have patience